# Как в javascript прописать работу кнопок

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Есть две формы из formfilter для wordpress'a. Первая форма отвечает за простой фильтр, а второй за расширенный. Надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, исчезала одна форма и появлялась другая.
Как это реализовать через javascript? Можете дать ссылку на то, через что это реализуется? Пыталась своими силами прописать, ничего не получилось=\

```
  <?php echo do_shortcode( ' [pfg form="2"]' ); ?>.
  <?php echo do_shortcode( ' [pfg form="1"]' ); ?>.
```

Comment: Что такое formfilter?

Comment: form filter это плагин для wordpress по формированию фильтров для поиска

Comment: я перефразирую, мне важно просто реализовать принцип "нажимаю на 1 кнопку, появляется 1 фигня и пропадает 2ая, нажимаю на вторую и обратная ситуация"
и главное, чтобы все это работало с php элементами

Comment: http://www.jooom.ru/toster/vanilla10.php

Answer (score 1):

Пример - http://www.jooom.ru/toster/vanilla10.php

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener( 'click' , function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  document.querySelector('.panel').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам нужно выбрать кнопку через querySelector,или getElementById и  установить на нее listener, на событие клика.
2. Написать функцию которая будет срабатывать по нажатии на кнопку - в ней нужно выбрать блок, можно опять же через querySelector,или getElementById, который вы хотите скрыть и скрыть его добавив класс, или просто стиль скрывающий элемент, например, display:none, или visibility:hidden.
3. Аналогочно со второй кнопкой.